# MAMP mod_rewrite returns 301

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mamp

I'm having trouble to set up MAMP correctly together with mod_rewrite.
My `.htaccess` looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /api/

RewriteRule ^booking/add/?$ booking.php [NC,L]
```

On my Webserver everything is working fine, but running the script locally doesn't work. The response header from MAMP looks like this:

```
Location:   http://test.local:8888/api/booking.php
```

Which then resolves in `We are sorry, but Chrome API does not allow to get a response body for redirect.`

Any idea how to fix this?
Thanks :)

Comment: Turn off MultiViews ...

Comment: Thanks a lot, turning off multi views and restarting the servers helped! :)